# How include the Swiper slider in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, banner-slider, slideshow

I tried to include the **swiper slider js**. but not working.

> Step1:

I have placed the css and js in my theme folder and add the below code in requirejs-config.js

```
var config = { 
    map: {
        '*': {
            'swipeslider':'js/swiper.min'
        }
    }
};
```

> Step2: add the template file banner.phtml in my theme folder

```
<div class="banner">
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url('images/banner_img.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>          
<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'swipeslider',
], function ($) {       
         var swiper = new Swiper('.banner .swiper-container', {
          pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            clickable: true,
          },
          loop:true,
          autoplay: {
            delay:5000,
          },
          simulateTouch:false,

        });        
});
```

But we got error message in browser console as **"Swiper is not defined"**.

Comment: Check the swiper.min.js is loaded or not on your page?

Comment: swiper.min.js not loaded in pagesource

Comment: Did you check any other console error?

Comment: i got only one error. Swiper is not defined

Comment: Is it loaded on require config Js?

Comment: no. not loading.

Comment: Then something related to cache.

Comment: I have already deleted folders from pub and var  and execute the upgrade, deploy commands. But sill i have same issues

Comment: Can you give me the url of swiper which one you are using?

Comment: http://idangero.us/swiper/

Comment: What is the directory location of your requirejs-config.js? What is the module name your are using for that slider?

Comment: app\design\frontend\Vendors\Sample\Magento_Theme. Just i created a template file and called in home page cms page

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: are you using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nolimits4web/swiper/master/dist/js/swiper.js??

Answer (score 2):

Below is my working code. Add this to your requirejs-config.js file:

```
var config = {
    paths: {            
            'swipeslider': "Magento_Theme/js/swiper"
        },   
    shim: {
        'swipeslider': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Then add your swiper.min.js to

> app\design\frontend\Vendors\Sample\Magento_Theme\web\js\swiper.min.js

and requirejs-config.js to

> app\design\frontend\Vendors\Sample\Magento_Theme\requirejs-config.js

Use the below js on your phtml instead of yours:

```
 <script>
    (function  () {
        require(["jquery","swipeslider"],function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var swiper = new Swiper('.banner .swiper-container', {
                                  pagination: {
                                    el: '.swiper-pagination',
                                    clickable: true,
                                  },
                                  loop:true,
                                  autoplay: {
                                    delay:5000,
                                  },
                                  simulateTouch:false
                                });       
            });
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Still i have same issues. Is anything changes in swiper.min.js?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Also what is magento 2 version? If its 2.1.x then delete the _requirejs folder from pub/static/_requirejs and then deploy the contents again and try.

Comment: Hi,  i have used the Magento 2.2.4.  Already i deleted the pub and var folders also deploy the content. There is no folder and file (_requirejs ) under  pub/static. In my console error as "ReferenceError: Swiper is not defined Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: http://192.168.1.24:8080/demo/ver1/pub/static/version1529063287/frontend/Vendors/Sample/fr_CA/Magento_Theme/js/swiper.min.js
Source Map URL: swiper.min.js.map"

Comment: Can you check the pub path if its added to that particular directoy or not?

Comment: Can you add swiper.min.js.map to the same js directory and also to pub/static......Magento_Theme/js?

Comment: i got below error.  <anonymous>
http://192.168.1.24:8080/demo/ver1/:665:21
fire
http://192.168.1.24:8080/demo/ver1/pub/static/version1529067705/frontend/Vendors/Sample/fr_CA/jquery.js:3232:12
fireWith
http://192.168.1.24:8080/demo/ver1/pub/static/version1529067705/frontend/Vendors/Sample/fr_CA/jquery.js:3362:8
ready
http://192.168.1.24:8080/demo/ver1/pub/static/version1529067705/frontend/Vendors/Sample/fr_CA/jquery.js:3582:4

Comment: use swiper.js instead of swiper.min.js.

Comment: no luck. same issues.

Comment: Then try different slider rather than swiper.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try with adding 'Swiper' in the Require call?

For example for Vimeo api use in Magento 2, you have to do something like this:

```
define([
'jquery',
'vimeo-sdk',
'domReady!'
], function($, Player) {
    let vimeoInst = new Player('iframe');
});
```

Probably with Swiper is the same. If you check the lib/dist/src of them has a `return Swiper;` at the end of it.

**Update: I tested and works.**

```
define([
'jquery',
'swiper',
'domReady!'
], function($, Swiper) {
    let carousel = new Swiper('.element',{/*your parameters*/});
});
```

Don't put the lib/dist/src of the Swiper JavaScript inside a require/define the structure. Include it straightforward and just map it in requirejs-config.js

Answer (score 0):

In require js:

```
var config = {
 map: {
            '*': {
                swiper: 'js/swiper.min',
                viewPageSwiper :  'js/viewpage-swiper',
            }
        },
        shim: {
            swiper: {
                deps: ['jquery']
            }
        }
};
```

In js file :

```
define([
        "jquery",
        "swiper"
    ],
    function ($, Swiper) {
        "use strict";

        //complete look
        var swiper = new Swiper('.complete-look-product .swiper-container', {
            slidesPerView: 'auto',
            spaceBetween: 10,
            freeMode: true,
            breakpoints: {
                1024: {
                    slidesPerView: 4,
                    spaceBetween: 40,
                },
                768: {
                    slidesPerView: 3,
                    spaceBetween: 30,
                },
                470: {
                    slidesPerView: 2,
                    spaceBetween: 10,
                }
            }
        });
```

In /Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/swiper.min.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Css: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/tree/master/dist/css
JS: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/tree/master/dist/js

Answer (score 0):

Add an argument for Requier and try again

```
<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'swipeslider',
], function ($, Swiper) {       
         var swiper = new Swiper('.banner .swiper-container', {
          pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            clickable: true,
          },
          loop:true,
          autoplay: {
            delay:5000,
          },
          simulateTouch:false,

        });        
});
</script>
```